# How to install PyPdf2 in PyCharm (Windows-64 bits)

Tags: python, windows, package, pycharm, pypdf

I want to install **PyPdf2** in PyCharm for Windows (64 bits)
I have tried to go to Settings\Project\Project Interpreter, Then pressing the "+" sign, but It did not found PyPdf2.

- I already Installed it to the normal python2.7 by going to the extracted path of PyPdf2 then I run (`python.exe setup.py install`)
- I tried to install it to anaconda by "`conda install -c mbonix pypdf2=1.24`" but I got an error "`Error Could not find URL: https://pythonhosted.org/PPdf2/Win-64/`"
- I tried to install it to anaconda by "`conda install -c anaconda-nb-extensions pypdf2=1.24`" but I got an error "`Error Could not find URL: https://pythonhosted.org/pypi/PPdf2/Win-64/`"
- I added the repository "https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/" to PyCharm, but it did not show PyPdf2 either!

What Can I do to install such module to PyCharm

Note: I use the Latest version 2016.2.2 of PyCharm Community edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can resolve this..
Go to command prompt and type pip install PyPDF2
Also go to pycharm and open "python packages" search for PyPDF2 and install it..
Hopefully it should work..
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the a look at the documentation to install library

[Pycharm Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: I reviewed the documentations before and installed several packages, but I found the problems with pyPdf2 only, as I described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pip install PyPDF2 in the command line? pycharm will access the Lib location C:\Users\DragonMaster\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages.